# How to update label from UITextField on press of button

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uibutton, uitextfield

So I know this might be an easy thing to do, but I am beginning with swift for macOS and swift development. I want to make a simple app that asks for a name, then says "Hello, name". In macOS development a way to do this is by doing this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: NSTextField!
.
// More code here
.
@IBAction func helloButton(_ sender: Any) {
    var name = nameField.stringValue
    if name.isEmpty{
        name = "World"
    }

    let greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
    helloLabel.stringValue = greeting
}
```

Is there anyway to do this or something similar for iOS? I tried to do this for iOS but it is not working for me. "nameField.stringValue" doesnt exist. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about nameField.text ?

Comment: what about the property `text` of NSTextField  in nameField.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
.
// More code here
.
@IBAction func helloButton(_ sender: Any) {
   var name = nameField.text!
   if name.isEmpty {
      name = "World"
   }

   let greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
    helloLabel.text = greeting
}
```

Comment: `UITextField` `text` property returns an optional string `String?`. Note that it has an empty string as default value, so it would never return nil even if you assign nil to it. So it is OK to force unwrap its value.  `var name = nameField.text!`

Comment: To everyone who helped, thank you very much. This solution + the force unwrapping suggestion solved the issue I was having.

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh No. The nil coalescing operator would never be called

Comment: Please re-read my comment. try assigning nil to the text property and then check `if nameField.text == nil`. it will return false

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //created a string variable
    var name: String = ""

    //our label to display input
    @IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!

    //this is the text field we created
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldName: UITextField!

    @IBAction func buttonClick(sender: UIButton) {
        //getting input from Text Field
        name = textFieldName.text!

        //Displaying input text into label
        labelName.text = "Hello \(name)"
    }
}
```

Here is the output -

[image]

Reference - https://www.simplifiedios.net/xcode-text-field-tutorial-ios-using-swift/

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you could get the string value of a textfield by using its [`text`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text) property:

```
let greeting = "Hello, \(nameField.text!.isEmpty ? "World" : nameField.text!)"
helloLabel.text = greeting
```

Although `text` property is an *optional* string, it has an empty string as default value, so it never returns `nil` even if you assign nil to it (thanks to [@Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) for the note).

Also, you could set the `UILabel` (`helloLabel`) by its [`text`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620538-text) property as mentioned above.

Comment: Btw you can use UIKeyInput `hasText` property https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput

Comment: `"Hello, " + (nameField.hasText ?  nameField.text! : "World")`

Comment: @LeoDabus good point! I'm not sure if there is any difference between `name.hasText` and `!name.text!.isEmpty` functionality, I still prefer using `name.hasText` since it specified to the `UIKeyInput`... Thanks alot :)

Comment: The only difference is its availability iOS10+.  You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
@IBAction func helloButton(_ sender: Any) {
let name = txtSearch.text
        if !name!.isEmpty {
            helloLabel.text = "Hello, \(name)"
        }
}
```

Comment: this would result in Optional("whatever") if you don't unwrap your optional string before your string interpolation